# 'fold up' sections of code - like when you close a control structure

Tags: optimization

I remember that there was a tag which made it possible to fold multiple lines.

e.g. like if you would fold down a for loop:

[image]

to

[image]

Is there a tag which makes this possible? Or is this an IDE specific tag?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the language and ide/editor.

In C# there are #region's that can be used for this. In some editors you can enable folding on all scopes (brackets). In some editors you can teach the editor to enable folding on comments with brackets in them ("//{" "//}").

In most cases this is an editor option that has to be enabled and configured.

What editor are you using? (and what language is this, JavaScript?)

For netbeans checkout the following: (You don't need to go past the first one)

- http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomCodeFolds - Manual method
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/SurroundWithCodeFolding - Code Template
- https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_folding/cf_uispec.html#custom - Talks about the how they work.

Example from first article:

```
// <editor-fold>
   Your code goes here...
// </editor-fold>
```

Comment: PHP and JavaScript on Netbeans.

Comment: I've added links for Netbeans.